# socketstream app throwing 404 not found

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-code-404, socketstream

I'm trying to load the socketstream application with express and cors, which is throwing an error stating 404. All the project directories are available in browser but no contents.

```
var app = require('express')();
var ss = require('socketstream');
var cors = require('cors');

ss.client.define('main', {
  view : 'app.html',
  css : [],
  code : [],
  tmpl : '*'
});

app.use(cors());


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.serve('main');
});

ss.start(app.listen(port));
```

And this is the response in browser

Headers

```
Remote Address:"RemoteAddress":"Port"
Request URL:http://"RemoteAddress":"Port"/_serveDev/code/app/someFile.js?ts=1449057700740&pathPrefix=app
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

Request headers

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:76
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 02 Dec 2015 12:03:20 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Powered-By:Express
```

Response headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:"RemoteAddress":"Port"
Referer:http://"RemoteAddress":"Port"/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
```

Update

The app.html is getting loaded in browser but 404 is only for scripts and css that is being requested from app.html.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the permissions of the files by running

```
sudo chmod 777 -R *
```

in the code directory.